# lxml wont install during uspto-opendata-python pip install

Tags: python

I'm trying to scrape USPTO with the documentation here:

https://docs.ip-tools.org/uspto-opendata-python/pbd.html

But the issue is that `lxml` wont install during the `uspto-opendata-python` pip install.

How do bypass this issue?

An alternative is to scrape with requests and determine the text from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular API doesn't seem to play well with newer Python versions.

I just tried 3.7.9 and it worked, no fuss!

Answer (score 0):

You can try "pip install lxml" before installing uspto-opendata-python. This worked for me. I found this suggestion elsewhere also. May find these links useful - https://pypi.org/project/xml-python/, https://lxml.de/installation.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: yeah i tried that